# Are difference between named arrow function and anonymous arrow function in JSX Props?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Example with ComponentA:

```
Case 1: with named arrow function callback: 
const ComponentA = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {... /* do somthing */};
  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>Hello world</div>
  )
}
```

```
Case 2: with anonymous arrow function callback:
const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => {/* Do sumthing here */}}>Hello world</div>
  )
}
```

I knowed case 1 and case 2 make child rerender, but I dont know about effect to memory leak.

Are there issues related to memory leak when use anonymous arrow function vs named arrow function ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's just your code's readability. There's no performance differences for as far as i am aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions are always anonymous. What you're referring to as the named arrow function is actually a function assignment

```js
// function assignment, function itself is not named
const handleClick = () => {};
```

As far as the performance difference, there is no difference. Both will create a new reference on each rerender.

Comment: Thanks @Haseeb Anwar . 
Somebody says Case 2 cause memory leak, because the arrow function is not assign to specific variable . 
Can you give me the evaluate about opinion above ?

Comment: No, generally it doesn't cause a memory leak. You need to be more specific about the problem to determine if this causes a memory leak